# Wordpress adding a hook for multiple functions with reference to class

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to use `add_action` to hook 2 functions and right now this is what I have:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_function_1', array (
            $this,
            'function_1'
        ) );
```

I tried adding the second function like so:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_function_1', array (
            $this,
            'function_1',
            'function_2'
        ) );
```

But this doesn't allow either of the functions to work. What is the proper way to do it other than declaring a separate `add_action` call?

Comment: There isn't, second param in `add_action()` function is [callback](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php), call another function inside first one.

Answer (score 1):

You may call second function inside first one as @Danijel wrote in comments. e.g. something like this may work:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test-action', 'first_1');        
 function first_1() {
    $a = 'abc';
    //call second funtion here

    $c = second_2();
    return  $a.$c;
 }       


 function second_2() {
    $b = 123;
    return  $b;
 }
```